# Connecting talnd to MySQL [transation read-only status server]

Tags: mysql, talend

I am trying to connect Talend (version 7.0.1) to MySQL Server (version 8.0.12), I can successfully connect and perform simple select queries to the database. However as soon as I try to perform a bulk Insert I get the following exception:

```
Starting job A_2_ProcessRestData_NEW at 17:59 20/08/2018.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3407
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tDBOutputBulkExec_1_tMBE (A_2_ProcessRestData_NEW)
java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:949)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3976)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3947)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:788)
    at living_dashboard.a_2_processrestdata_new_0_1.A_2_ProcessRestData_NEW.tFileInputDelimited_1Process(A_2_ProcessRestData_NEW.java:4671)
    at living_dashboard.a_2_processrestdata_new_0_1.A_2_ProcessRestData_NEW.runJobInTOS(A_2_ProcessRestData_NEW.java:6955)
    at living_dashboard.a_2_processrestdata_new_0_1.A_2_ProcessRestData_NEW.main(A_2_ProcessRestData_NEW.java:6733)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'tx_read_only'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2781)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3970)
    ... 6 more
[statistics] disconnected

Job A_2_ProcessRestData_NEW ended at 17:59 20/08/2018. [exit code=1]
```

Do you have any clue on what might be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does normal `insert` work fine? And what is this system variable `tx_read_only` exactly?

Comment: Hi. No, normal insert also outputs "Could not retrieve transation read-only status server". Regarding tx_read_only. For what I understand is a variable that defines that the database is read-only. In my understanding, During the connection, Talend asks for this variable back, although the serve cannot provide it because it does not exist. If I type the command "SELECT @@session.tx_read_only " the ouput is "select @@tx_read_only LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable 'tx_read_only'"

Comment: So, According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/added-deprecated-removed.html, the variable tx_read_only was removed in 8.0.3 version. I have the 8.0.12. So, either updating the driver or downgrading mysql version should work. Fingers crossed. Lets hope

Comment: All the best, I have very little to no knowledge on `MySql` so couldn't provide much help on this.

Answer (score -1):

I eventually solved the question. It turns out that the **DB Version to be used cannot be MySQL 5** as I was specifying. I need to use **MariaDB** instead. Problem solved ;)